# Vuetify Pagination Selected Page Not Displaying

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm working with Vuetify pagination component.  I followed the instruction on how to set it up including the necessary modules ([vuetify pagination page](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/paginations)).  I have it working except when I select the page, the selected button is showing plain white, the page number is not displayed and it's not highlighted.  This is how it looks. [vuetify pagination not showing selected page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6upT.png).

Has anyone else have this issue?  How did you fix it?

Comment: Reproduce on [codepen](https://template.vuetifyjs.com/).

Comment: When you inspect the button element which classes are applied to it?